# group by chunks

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have large customer database with various points balances. I would like to group them by 5000 points.

Expected results:

```
0-5k 100 Members
5-10k 120 Members
10-15K 200 Members etc
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Derlik01 I notice that you have asked a few questions like this, please note that StackOverflow is not a code golf, or quiz site, but for asking questions about real problems. Are you asking these questions because you have a real need for the answer? In that case, please provide more context, otherwise you will probably get downvoted, and your questions closed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select floor(points / 5000), count(*) as num_members
from t
group by floor(points / 5000)
order by min(points);
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select
count(Distinct MemberID ) as "num_members",
floor(points / 5000) as "Bucket"
from t
group by floor(points / 5000)
order by floor(points / 5000) ASC
```